# How can I use uploaded .sql database in filezilla which I have been exported through xampp server.

Tags: php, sql, database

I am making a site in PHP. I have registered a domain and uploaded my PHP pages in filezilla using that host address and password. But I don't have any Idea about how to use database which I have made in xampp server. Somewhere I found an answer stated as
1.Export your database into a *`.sql` file
2.upload it to your webserver
3.In a php page, do commands to connect to your database, and then run a command like
this:

```
mysql_query("SOURCE path/to/sqlfile.sql");
```

Then hit that PHP page with your web browser

Can any one help me explaining this solution more precisely. I mean what command should I give in PHP page for connecting to database.

If there is any other way to use database of xampp server then pls suggest me. I will be thankful Your answers.

Comment: Good God, please don’t have commands ran by a web-accessible PHP script! Do it the proper way: connect to your MySQL database directly and then import the **.sql** file. Your web host will be able to tell you how to connect to your database (assuming one’s already been created).

Comment: what to use in place of hostname,password,username and db_name in  thai query. When I was using local data base then hostname was localhost, username was root and db_name was the name of data base I had made in xampp $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","db_name");

Comment: Like I say, your hosting provider will be able to advise you on the details to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install mysql.
Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

Then in php you can create a mysql object

```
$db=new mysqli($host,$user,pass);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: what to use in place of hostname,password,username and db_name in thai query. When I was using local data base then hostname was localhost, username was root and db_name was the name of data base I had made in xampp $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","db_name");